# Replace background image reference with other class in scss

Tags: sass

I have couple of CSS classes in my SCSS file:

```
#close {
  position:absolute;
  background:url(../images/close.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  display:block;
  top:-15px;
  right:-15px;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

#close:hover {
  background:url(../images/close_hover.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

I am wondering if it is possible to replace the image references in this SCSS file with classes that are residing in a different SCSS file that's generated for image sprites.

```
.modal_close { width: 33px; height: 33px; background-position: 0 0 }
.modal_close_hover { width: 33px; height: 33px; background-position: -390px -51px }
```

Comment: What precisely do you want to replace in the background declaration? Do you want the background-image file reference to be "modal" rather than a file?

Comment: Yes, instead of pointing at the image, point at the same definition used in second css, by name, because the file is generated automatically and the position changes.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the generated CSS you expect to see for those two declarations?